# How do I deal with these scaling and positioning issues in Tikzcd

Tags: positioning, tikz-cd, scaling

I have been trying for a while with this one, but I can't get the 'a's to be further from the arrows and the dot for the $f$ to be bigger.

I tried quiverapp, but the problem with the dot persists. Scaling doesn't seem to work so easily in Tikzcd.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    {} \arrow[r, "a", no head,marrow=>] & \Dot{\text{$f$}} \arrow[r, "a", no head, marrow =>] & {}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Is there a relatively simple way to get it to look better (a's a bit further up, f a bit further down)?

What I was referring to with the quiverapp version is here below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\let\oldpercent\%
\renewcommand{\%}{\scalebox{0.85}{\oldpercent}}


\tikzset{
    marrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{#1}}}, postaction=decorate}
}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
            {}&  \Dot{\text{$f$}} & {}
            \arrow["a", no head, marrow=>, from=1-1, to= 1-2]
            \arrow["a", no head, marrow=>, from=1-2, to= 1-3]
            \end{tikzcd}\]
    
\end{document}
```

This is interesting because The labels on the arrows seem to be at nice heights.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please provide a bit more code? It would be great to have a [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/).

Comment: Certainly! I'll write something up now

Comment: Please provide the defintion for `marrow` and also which packages you use or at least what is meant with `\Dot`.

Comment: Right, I included my preamble. Also I included the definition of `marrow`

Comment: You can add to the `\tikzset` macro another entry: `commutative diagrams/every label/.append style={inner sep=0.75ex}`. Entries are to be separated with a comma. This will shift the a a bit upwards.

Comment: That did the trick for the a! Thanks very much. Now for some way to either make `\Dot` larger, or to be able to index `\bullet` or something like this

Comment: And then, the dot on the f is an accent which cannot be scaled easily. You need to create your own symbol or stitch something together TikZ. You should just write `\dot{f}` anyways.

Comment: Right, it's tough because if I were to use any scaling (like `\Huge`) even with `\dot`, I end up scaling the `f`. Also I used `\Dot` because I saw that it seemed to work in these diagrams
https://newbedev.com/new-to-tikz-how-can-this-figure-be-drawn-with-tikz

Comment: Oh, well, then just use their macro. Place this in your preamble: `\newcommand\Dot[1]{\bullet\atop #1}`. It will probably throw an error because `\Dot` might have been defined by another package, but you can choose another name such as `\bigdot` and then write `\bigdot{f}` to type it.

Comment: ok so reading those very examples a bit more I realized `\Dot` there meant `\bullet\atop {}` but this still leaves some space in the middle. What a  coincidence we came upon this at the same time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the `inner sep` of the label nodes, which will make them shift away from the arrow.

As for a bigger dot: Since you provided a link in the comments to another example that shows that you essentially would like to place a `\bullet` on top of the f, you could use this approach maybe (although I feel that such a bullet is a bit too large):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\bigdot[1]{%
    \stackon[1pt]{#1}{\bullet}%
}

\tikzset{
    marrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{#1}}}, postaction=decorate},
    commutative diagrams/every label/.append style={inner sep=0.75ex},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    {} & \bigdot{f} & {}
    \arrow["a", no head, marrow=>, from=1-1, to= 1-2]
    \arrow["a", no head, marrow=>, from=1-2, to= 1-3]
\end{tikzcd}
            
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to have the bullet centered with the arrows such as in the image below, then change the line `\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\bullet}` to `\stackunder[1pt]{\bullet}{#1}`:

[image]

Comment: This is quite good! what remains would be to make it so the bullet was "colinear" with the arrows. Sort of to lower the bullet and the f slightly. Sorry that this was not clear from the get go

Comment: You mean, that the f sort of hangs from the bullet? Then change `\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\bullet}` to `\stackunder[1pt]{\bullet}{#1}`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much for thinking about my problem