# Inside arrow in xy package: steps

Tags: xy-pic, xymatrix

Given the image

[image]

taken from this question here [How do I deal with these scaling and positioning issues in Tikzcd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623354/how-do-i-deal-with-these-scaling-and-positioning-issues-in-tikzcd),

> how is it possible to obtain an arrow inside a segment using only `xy` package?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
\ar@{->}[r]^{a} & f & 
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xy-pic there is an arrow modifier `\dir`. Using this modifier you can draw the arrow with the tip in the middle as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
\ar@{-}[r]|*\dir{>} & f & 
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The command `\dir` doesn't appear in the xy-pic user manual. It is the [xy-pic reference manual](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyrefer.pdf) in which this command is documented. (I don't know why there are many manuals for xy-pic with different contents)

Comment: Great Luis :-) I have not found this in the manual....thank you very very very.......much.....

Comment: It is nice to know that it is useful to you. You have not found that command in the manual because it is not there. I edited the answer with the corresponding "manual" in which you can see this and many other commands for xy.

Comment: Excellent Luis. I have the documentation of xy but often when there is not an example I not understand well the code :-).

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem with xy, maybe that was the main reason why I moved to tikz-cd

Comment: I like sometimes the old packages like xy. :-) I think that xy package is very large instead of tikz-cd.